# Use mySql innodb cluster sandbox after restart of system/ not working?

Tags: innodb, sandbox, mysql-innodb-cluster

During installation I selected Inno db cluster sandbox configration, which left me with sandbox running at 3310 and mySql server at 3306.  After restarting, nothing was working,how to restart and  reinitiate the Inno DB cluster sandbox? Apparrently I selected this option to just to check out what is Inno DB Cluster

[image: Configuration during installation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I had to go to multiple documentation to see what Inno DB cluster to solve this problem
You can use these in **mysqlsh**

`- startSandboxInstance`            Starts an existing MySQL Server instance on

`- rebootClusterFromCompleteOutage` Brings a cluster back ONLINE,If you dont run it , the instance will be on super read only mode. it will take 10 min , dont close it by thinking it is stuck.

Eg

```
dba.startSandboxInstance(3310)
dba.startSandboxInstance(3320)
dba.startSandboxInstance(3330)
```

Then run `dba.rebootClusterFromCompleteOutage()` to disable GR auto-initialisation and super read only mode

if it is showing the `Dba.rebootClusterFromCompleteOutage: An open session is required to perform this operation. (RuntimeError)`, use `\connect root@localhost:3310` and then use `dba.rebootClusterFromCompleteOutage()`

I am attaching my screenshot of how I used these commands with **mysqlsh**

[image]